# Windows Universal App. Setting icons in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, icons, font-awesome, win-universal-app

I'm trying to add some scaling to a Universal App and part of this involves replacing some text with icons.

With the below code I am able to set the icon in the XAML.

```
<TextBlock Name="HoursLabel" Text="&#xf017;" Style="{StaticResource DescriptionLabels}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"/>
```

However in the code behind (which sets the icon's code on a re-size event) the following only displays the text.

```
    private void ResponsivePage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HoursLabel.Text = "&#xf017;";
    }
```

I'm a little confused, do I need to apply the font family again in the code behind or am I missing something?

Edit:
My problem was that I was using codes in the format `"&#xf017;"`
 instead of `"\uF017"` pointed out by Jeffrey Chen. Replacing the "&#x" with "\uf" sorted out my problem.

Stanley1's answer also worked but I felt changing the format was cleaner.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm a little confused, do I need to apply the font family again in the
>   code behind or am I missing something?

No, you don’t need to apply the font family again.
XAML and .NET have different way to describe special characters.

In .NET, you should use this way:

```
HoursLabel.Text = "\uF017";
```

Comment: hmm any idea how to do this if I load it from my database (MySQL)?

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround it by putting 2 TextBlocks over each other on a grid.

One contains the icon defined in xaml.

The second one (HoursLabel_2) contains text.

By default :

```
HoursLabel.visibility = visibility.visible;
HoursLabel_2.visiblity = visibility.collapsed;
```

And on the re-size event you switch the Visibility Property.

Best of luck !